# The second best song ever

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

First word:

> ome say

Second word:

> Why didn't the skeleton go to the party? no____

Third word:

> ____, twice, thrice

Fourth word:

> word_a = "a striped orange animal"
>
> word_b = "not hot"
>
> print(word_a[0] + word_b[1] word_b[2] word_b[3])

Fifth word:

> ____ a name I call myself

Comment: The best is Africa by Toto

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got this far quicker than I care to admit...

> "All-Star" by Smash Mouth

First word:

> **SOME** say

Second word:

> He had no **BODY** to go with

Third word:

> **ONCE**, twice, thrice

Fourth word:

> **TOLD** (first letter of **t**iger, last three letters of c**old**)

Fifth word:

> **ME** a name I call myself

All together now:

> Somebody once told me (the world was gonna roll me, I ain't the sharpest tool in the sheeeed...~)

Comment: Well done! This is a good song, and if the ends justify the memes...

Comment: To be honest, I was kind of expecting a rickroll here, but great answer and great puzzle!! :D

Comment: I know how sing this whole song… Don't ask…

Comment: @Yout Ried Same...